# Вопрос по MathCad

Tags: функции, mathcad

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть вот такая функция и нужно задать параметр x+z=1. Может кто знает как это сделать?

Comment: Если мне не изменяет склероз, нужно построить плоскость z = 1 = x и намалевать кривую их пересечения.

Comment: Можете описать как на рисовать такую плокость

Answer (score 0):

Там `z = 1 - x` или `f(x,z) = z + x - 1` в вашем случае.
Маткад последний раз я отрывал лет 20 назад, так что... Но вот так оно выглядит в онлайн 3д программулине: https://c3d.libretexts.org/CalcPlot3D/index.html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в формуле 9*10^2, 9-я степень плохо масштабируется.